# Matrix indexing for fast sums by group

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I am running into an out of memory issue when running simulations in MATLAB.

To give an easy example, let's say I have a MATLAB table / matrix / collection of vectors that look like this:

```
 id | t | var
----+---+-----
  1 | 1 | 100
  1 | 2 | 150
  2 | 2 | 200
  2 | 3 |  90
  2 | 4 | 980
```

where `id` denotes individuals, `t` denotes time periods, and `var` is a numerical variable.

I need to sum the different values of `var` for a given individual `id` over time `t`. The easiest way I could find was to do run the following:

```matlab
idx    = sparse(id == id');
sumvar = idx*sumvar;
```

which produces the desired result (a vector with the same length as `var` where each element is the sum for a given `id`).

```
 id | t | var | sumvar 
----+---+-----+--------
  1 | 1 | 100 |   250  
  1 | 2 | 150 |   250  
  2 | 2 | 200 |  1270  
  2 | 3 |  90 |  1270   
  2 | 4 | 980 |  1270
```

The problem is that computing `idx` is *extremely* computer intensive, and with vectors of the order of 150,000 my computer runs out of memory.

One potential solution is to use the following code:

```matlab
len = length(id);
idx = sparse(len,len);
for i = 1:len
   idx(id == id(i),:) = 1;
end
```

But that seems to be quite slow.

I feel this is a problem someone else may have already faced. Is there anything that could be both non-computing intensive but also fast enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html), as follows. Let your data be

```
id = [1 1 2 2 2].';
var = [100 150 200 90 980].';
```

- Assuming `id` always contains integer entries starting at `1`:

  ```
  result = accumarray(id, var);
  ```

  gives

  ```
  result =
           250
          1270
  ```
- If `id` is arbitrary, use:

  ```
  [~, ~, id_int] = unique(id);
  result = accumarray(id_int, var);
  ```
- If you need the results repeated as with your code, add:

  ```
  result_repeated = result(id_int);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following, still using a loop, but in a bit more efficient way by iterating over only the unique `id`'s.

```
id = [1 1 2 2 2].';
var = [100 150 200 90 980].';

unique_ids = unique(id);    % get the unique ids
sum_var = NaN(size(var));   % init the sum_var vector

for k = unique_ids.'        % loop over the ids
    idx = find(id == k);    % find indices per id
    sum_var(idx) = sum(var(idx));   % sum per id
end
```

Or, if you just need a vector with the sum per `id`:

```
unique_ids = unique(id);           % get the unique idx
sum_var = NaN(size(unique_ids));   % init the sum_var vector

for k = 1:numel(unique_ids)
    idx = find(id == unique_ids(k));    % find indices per id
    sum_var(k) = sum(var(idx));         % sum per id
end
```

---

**Update:** It can also be done without `find`, by using the indices per unique element that `unique` can return. **Assuming your data is sorted by `id`** you can do the following:

```
[unique_ids, start_idx, ~] = unique(id);  % get the unique idx, and the first occuring idx per id

sum_var = NaN(size(unique_ids));

start_idx = [start_idx; numel(var)+1];    % append total number of elements+1 for last summation in loop below

for k = 1:numel(unique_ids)
    ids = start_idx(k):start_idx(k+1)-1;  % indices in table for specific id
    sum_var(k) = sum(var(ids));
end
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, although find was computing-intensive. Selected the other answer b/c it is a way where I don't have to bother constructing `idx` to begin with!

Answer (score 0):

For your example table `T`:

```
 id | t | var
----+---+-----
  1 | 1 | 100
  1 | 2 | 150
  2 | 2 | 200
  2 | 3 |  90
  2 | 4 | 980
```

You can use `varfun`

```
a = varfun( @sum, T, 'GroupingVariables', 'id', 'InputVariables', 'var' )
```

Result:

```
a =
2×3 table
id    GroupCount    sum_var
__    __________    _______
1     2              250   
2     3             1270
```